# Vue3 and Element plus dynamic column not show data

Tags: vuejs3, element-plus

I try to loop through Element-plus table column  as  `<el-table-column v-for="(d ,i) in data.values" :key="i" :prop="d.value" :label="d.label" />` but no result showed in browser I trying google for hours and trying several examples and solutions but nothing works for me on this issue.

full example here

```html
<template>
  <el-table :data="data" class="full-table">

    <el-table-column fixed prop="name" label="Employee" width="250"/>
    <el-table-column prop="phone" label="Phone"/>
    <el-table-column v-for="(d ,i) in data.values" :key="i" :prop="d.value" :label="d.label" />

  </el-table>

</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {ElTable, ElTableColumn} from 'element-plus'

const data = [
  {
    name: 'personal1',
    phone: 6767000,
    values: [
      {
        label: 'email',
        value: 'personal1@mail.com',
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'personal2',
    phone: 9090000,
    values: [
      {
        label: 'email',
        value: 'personal2@mail.com',
      }
    ]
  },

]


</script>
```

The result is show like this no extra column for v-for
[image: Result in browser]

What do i do wrong?. please advice

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `value` in the `template` as [explained here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping-in-templates).
Try with `v-for="(d ,i) in data"` and `:prop="d"`.

Also, feel free to double check what you have in your Vue devtools to be sure.

I don't have an Element UI example but this [is how the Vue part works](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqtUktuwjAUvMqTNykSJCkLEFFA7TlqFiYxYOqfbCdVFeXufXaAoqqLLuqF/X6eGWs8kFdr877jpCJ14MpKFviOaoC6FT30i6NxW0qeWpiLGQgNLQuMEqje+SfW21wzxWNunbGxEGPJDlymbooo2Q0DTKMwjnWByEhRFw98mPrGCRvA89BZkEyfECF4vEy1UNa4AAM4zpogeoSBozMKMlSeRbVUN0b7kOTB9j739BabQ9wAIn8FmeXOG83kczaf6vZsNDZW69W6LMtrsWey476CBBDXFSSu9CpE4ooJeUO5X3qkeIkTeWPU99Q4Bft4jKn6u7zlD3mbcoPq/lXe8g/y9rPo1OTNjszJZMVCMZtfEAS/TWKm1wb6Vd20UILuxJyScwjWV0Xhj038bBefG3cqMMpdp4NQPOdeLQ7OfHjuEJiSxE/1SMYvtgTSMw==) when using the Composition API.

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="(d ,i) in data" :key="d.name" :prop="d" :label="d.label">
    {{ d.name }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { reactive } from 'vue'
  
const data = reactive([
  {
    name: 'personal1',
    phone: 6767000,
    values: [
      {
        label: 'email',
        value: 'personal1@mail.com',
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'personal2',
    phone: 9090000,
    values: [
      {
        label: 'email',
        value: 'personal2@mail.com',
      }
    ]
  },
])
</script>
```

Overall, I recommend that you give a read to [that part](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-reactive-state) of the doc to have a fully usable Vue example with some working reactivity.
Element UI's prop will follow up accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. but is not what i want. I want to loop through `<el-table-column .../> ` the problem is  not displayed in browser via `v-for` but first and second `<el-table-column>` are showed up. and i want the email data inside values `values: [{ label: 'email', value: 'personal2@mail.com'  }]`